# Bug in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

I've got a bug when I'm using a javascript function : my function displays the content of a div element but when I uncomment some code it doesn't work anymore.
Someone has any idea why ?

```
    function traverse(){
        var root=document.getElementById('tree0').childNodes;
        for(var i=0;i<root.length;i++) {
                var lis = root[i];
                var number =0;
                for (var member in lis) {
                    output.innerHTML+=lis[member];
                    /*var assertion = lis[member];
                    var result = assertion.indexOf("Bookmarks menu");
                    if(result != -1) {
                       output.innerHTML+='Test';
                    }*/

                 }
         }
     }
```

thanks,

Bruno

Comment: @Raynos I don't know (lis[member].type = undefined)

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering but I mispelled only when I copied the source code so the error is not here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get more that you expect when you do *for ... in ...*

Is THIS what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/bM9Bn/

```
<div id="tree0">
  <div id="bla">
    bla
  </div>
  <div id="Bookmarks menu">
    Bookmarks Menu
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
var output = document.getElementById("output")
function traverse(){
  var root=document.getElementById('tree0').childNodes;
  for(var i=0;i<root.length;i++) {
    var lis = root[i];
    var number =0;
    for (var member in lis) {
//      output.innerHTML+="["+member+":"+lis[member]+"]";
      if (member == "id" || member == "textContent") {
        output.innerHTML+="["+member+":"+lis[member]+"]";
        var assertion = lis[member];
        // the typeof test not needed if we only process textContent and ID
        if (typeof assertion == "string") { 
          var result = assertion.indexOf("Bookmarks menu");
          if(result != -1) {
            output.innerHTML+='<span style="color:red">Test</span>';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
traverse()
</script>
```

Comment: @Bruno: What are you looking for. can we please see what the tree looks like. What in a node list can be the string "Bookmars menu" - I would expect asserion.innerHMTL or assertion.textContent or something

Comment: +1 from me. Dunno what the OP wants, but expecting all enumerable properties of a DOM element to be strings is not sensible. Searching through *every* property looking for a specific string doesn't make sense, surely the OP knows which property is relevant?

Comment: @RobG -yes, a document.getElementsByTagName or similar

Answer (score 0):

Just looking quickly- var and if statement should both us resultat?

var resultat = assertion.indexOf("Bookmarks menu"); 
                    if(result**at** != -1) {

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the 'result' variable, but setting the 'resultat' variable. Try using resultAt in the conditional, and I think it will work for you.